# Trying to convert a string into a date type in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, date, aggregation-framework

I am working with a real estate dataset in `MongoDB 4.2` and I have a field for the closing date named "Closing Date" (the date appears with the format `9/13/19`, for example), which is a string type field. I would like to change it to date type so that I can do some aggregation expressions and calculate average sale price per city PER MONTH. I tried to change the string to data type by doing the following:

```
db.real_estate.aggregate([{"$addFields":{"Sold on":{"$toDate":"$Closing Date"}}}])
```

I got the following error:

```
Failed to execute script.

Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Error parsing date string ''; 0: Empty string '\u0000'",
    "code" : 241,
    "codeName" : "ConversionFailure"
} : aggregate failed
```

Any suggestions???

Comment: Is your date is of type :: 9/13/19 or 09/13/19 (m/dd/yy or mm/dd/yy)?? Also do you want to update that field across all your documents or do you want to convert this every time you query DB keep data as is ?

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of weird format, I've tried to use few operators from mongoDB but it didn't work well, as you wanted to group on month you can try below, but my suggestion is to think through data flowing in & out to your DB & store field types accordingly/much supported formats - which would make it simple on further transactions.

**Please try this query :**

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{ $addFields: { date: { $substrCP: ["$date", 0, 2] } } }, {
    $project:
    {
        date: {
            $cond: {
                if: {
                    "$regexMatch": {
                        "input": "$date",
                        "regex": /^\w+$/
                    }
                }, then: { $toInt: '$date' }, else: { $toInt: { $substrCP: ["$date", 0, 1] } }
            }
        }
    }
}, { $group: { _id: '$date', monthCount: { $sum: 1 }, data: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } }
])
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "monthCount" : 1.0,
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5df3b9b79c25aca5b3a508f5"),
            "date" : 1
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 10,
    "monthCount" : 1.0,
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5df3b9b09c25aca5b3a508f2"),
            "date" : 10
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 9,
    "monthCount" : 2.0,
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5df3b9a29c25aca5b3a508ef"),
            "date" : 9
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5df3c8c89c25aca5b3a50b3f"),
            "date" : 9
        }
    ]
}
```

**Collection Date :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df3b9a29c25aca5b3a508ef"),
    "date" : "9/13/19"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df3b9b09c25aca5b3a508f2"),
    "date" : "10/13/19"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df3b9b79c25aca5b3a508f5"),
    "date" : "01/13/19"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df3c8c89c25aca5b3a50b3f"),
    "date" : "9/11/19"
}
```

Comment: I am going to try this now, thank you for you help!

Comment: @eurojourney : Did it work or still having any issues ?

Comment: Hello, I got stuck with this solution in the end (I am new to MongoDB) and really could not follow it all that well... however, I figured out a different way to solve my problem. Since I only needed to search by the month, I was able to use {$match:{"Closing Date":{$regex:"^9"}}} to search for the documents for the month of September, for example. I do however appreciate the time it took to develop this answer and your help.

Comment: @eurojourney: Ok it's completely irrelevant to the question then, maybe doing it might have yield req output in a diff way but it's not what is asked in question(match on a month & then avg'g Vs avg'ng on a whole is what differs)..!! Anyway if it's working, nice :-)